# How to POST data using Retrofit2?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm trying Retrofit 2.4.0 in my android application. Where do I have a login activity. I'm trying POST request but it return response code 404 in onResponse method. But It is working perfectly with POSTMAN and I getting correct data in log using `HttpLoggingInterceptor`. I have tried many methods to overcome this problem. My service code is.

```
@POST("user_login")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<ResponseBody> user_login(@Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String password);

@Multipart
@POST("user_login")
Call<ResponseBody> user_login(@PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody> bodyMap);

@Multipart
@POST("user_login")
Call<Status> user_login(@Part("email") RequestBody email, @Part("password") RequestBody password);

@POST("user_login")
Call<JSONObject> user_login(@Body String credentials);

@POST("user_login")
Call<User> user_login(@Body LoginCredentials credentials);
```

none of above methods aren't working.

I'm posting some other methods Which are I am using too.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
Cache provideOkHttpCache(TUK application) {
    int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MB
    return new Cache(application.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);
}

@Provides
@Singleton
Gson provideGson() {
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    // builder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
    return builder.create();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(Cache cache) {
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    builder.cache(cache);
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(message -> Logger.wtf("AppModule", message));
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    builder.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    return builder.build();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
Retrofit provideRetrofit(Gson gson, OkHttpClient client) {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .baseUrl(TUK.BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .build();
}
```

but I'm trying other URLs too with GET method are working perfectly.

my base url is like `"http://www.example.com/api/"`
and my `@PartMap()` code is

```
public static Map<String, RequestBody> getMap(LoginCredentials credentials) {
    Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("email", RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, credentials.getEmail()));
    map.put("password", RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, credentials.getPassword()));
    return map;
}
```

my `HttpLoggingInterceptor` logging data is

```
<-- 404 https://www.example.com/api/user_login (718ms)
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
.
.
.
.
{"status":false,"message":"Invalid User Email Or Password."}
<-- END HTTP (60-byte body)
```

and my `onResponse` methods logging data is

```
Response{protocol=h2, code=404, message=, url=https://www.example.com/api/user_login}
```

At the end my question is how to POST data using Retrofit.

I have stuck at this point. I have tried other solutions from stackoverflow but no help. Please guys help me out this problem. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.
[image: This is the form data image. i am sending data in the BODY field]

[image: This is header data image]

[image: This is raw data image]

Comment: Is there a need to pass multipartBody?Is it just loginId and passwords that you are using?

Comment: @ABr I don't know. I just tried. but no help.

Comment: No.From your code what i understood is that you don't need multipart data to make  a request

Comment: Are you passing the login credentials in body or in the url itself as fields?Basically is this is what we do                                                         
@POST("/api/user_login")
Call<User> user_login(@Body LoginCredentials credentials);

Comment: add your postman screenshot with header values

Comment: Multipart data is for sending files

Comment: @ABr i have tried other methods too. but no help.

Comment: You said The postman was working right!!! but the above screen shot shows error

Comment: yes @ABr,postman also returned `404`,it's will be url issue

Comment: First you make sure you are getting 200 OK in Postman then you proceed with the code .Because we don't know whats causing the problem yet

Comment: @ABr Rajasekaran M I have added raw data image. it show 404 code as well as response. If it is a 404 error why it is returning response.

Comment: @RajasekaranM check my above comment

Comment: @JitendraSingh please add working postman screenshot

Comment: Probably be the problem of the server side

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to use the multipart body for POST request and it can be easily done by 
  below code. For example I have an base URL like http://example.com/api/

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("login")
Call<LoginResponse> login(@Field("email") String email,
                          @Field("password") String password);
```

The final call will be redirected to http://example.com/api/login in above case.

So in this case my call will be directed to http://example.com/api/login.
Or the other problem can be in your URL. As your base url is this "http://www.example.com/api/" and by joining the API which API name, it becomes this "http://www.example.com/api//api/user_login" which contains two "//" that can cause error in finding your API because of that it throws 404( which is not found). So please adjust your base URL accordingly. Hope that helps somehow.

Comment: @Ahmaz Izaz I checked this method too, but no help.

Comment: noticed this, but as he told the other apis are working so I thought this would not be a problem

Comment: @ABr I am getting JSON response in HttpLoggingInterceptor log. {"status":false,"message":"Invalid User Email Or Password."}. but not in onResponse method. It shows 404 code.

Comment: 404 can't be related with invalid credentials. Are you providing correct credentials

Comment: HTTP 404 is returned when the server is unable to find method to match your exact request.  @AbrahamMathew said 404 not related to invalid credentials. Please check your server side settings too

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a server mistake, 404 is the error code returned by server. Retrofit has requested success. But any request that the return code is not 200 will be considered a failed request. Retrofit will callback `onFailure()` method, you can get response in the following way.

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Call<News> call, Throwable t) {
       if(t instanceof HttpException){
            ResponseBody body=((HttpException) t).response().errorBody();
       }
}
```

> Tell your back end the meaning of [**404**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404),it should not be returned here

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by setting `builder.setLenient();`
complete code is

```
@Provides
@Singleton
Gson provideGson() {
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.setLenient(); // this line help me to get response.
// builder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
return builder.create();
}
```

thanks for your help guys.